# Splitting MySQL Database into separate databases

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, hibernate

I have a requirement that the MySQL database being used in my application is scaling very aggressively. I am in no state currently to migrate to a NoSQL Database.

I have figured out the following areas where I can try splitting the current database into multiple databases:

1. There are some tables which have static content, i.e. it changes barely.
2. There are user tables which store the user data upon interaction which changes drastically.

Now, if i split the database into two different databases, how will I handle the transaction? How will I write the Data Access Layer, will i have connections to both the databases? The application currently uses Spring & Hibernate for Back End. There are calls which join the user tables and the content tables in the current schema.

The architecture follows the current structure:
Controller -> Service -> DAO Layer.

So, if i am willing to refactor the DAO layer which communicates with the database, what approach should i follow? I know only about Hibernate ORM but i would be willing to letting it go if there is something better than Hibernate.

Comment: Presumably you mean "split into multiple servers" when you say "split into separate databases."

Comment: i mean, i have a database named 'test' which i want to split into 2 different databases, 'test1' and test2' The databases 'test1' and 'test2' will most probably be on the same server.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple databases on the same server? That approach will probably not improve performance on its own.  RAM, fast disks, optimization, partitioning, and correct indexing will have a far greater payback.

If you have multiple databases on one server you can connect to them with a single connection, and simply use the database names with the table names in your SQL.  Transactions work fine within a single connection.

Transactions across multiple connections and multiple servers are harder. There's a feature in MySQL called `XA` transactions to help handle this. But it has plenty of overhead, and is therefore most useful for high-value transactions as in banking.

In the jargon of the trade, adding servers is called "scale-out."  The alternative is "scale-up," in which you add more RAM, faster direct-access storage, optimization, and other stuff to a single server to get it to do more.

There are several approaches you can take to the scale-out problem. The classic one is to use MySQL to set up a single primary server with multiple load-balanced replica servers.. That's probably the path that's most often taken, so you can do it without reinventing a lot of wheels. In this solution you do all your writing to a single instance. Queries that look up data can use multiple read-only load-balanced instances.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-solutions-scaleout.html

This is a very popular approach where you have a mix of long-running reporting queries and short-running interactive queries. The reporting can be run on dedicated slave servers.

Another approach is multiple-primary-server replication using MySQL Cluster. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html

Another approach, if you have money to spend, is to go with a supported MySQL Cluster.  Oracle, MariaDB, and Percona have such products on offer.

Scale-out is a big job no matter how you approach it. There's some documented experience from other people who have done it.  For example, https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=23844338919

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you did not thought about the partition of your database.
You should read something about database normalization first: [database normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

To split the database i would export the sql code from the database, then i would make 2 new files were i copy the tables that i want to have in the specific databases. After that i would import the 2 files in the specific databases.

*i think this might help u help me: lets say i want to print reports for a user. the user is persisted in 'user' table and there is a score table which has the user score for every user_id. Now, my plan is to put the user table in one database, and score table in another database, making them two data sources. How can i handle such a scenario?*

First to put the tables in different databases make no sence for me and i did not know if there is a ability to make select queries with to different databases mixed.

example: SELECT score, name FROM user, score WHERE score > 100 AND(score.user_id = user.user_id);

I dont no if this fit with two databases i think not.

Comment: this part is easy, i split the database, but now how do i take care of the transactions happening between two different databases?

Comment: It's not easy to help you, when i dont know your database structure or something of your code.

Comment: i think this might help u help me:

lets say i want to print reports for a user. the user is persisted in 'user' table and there is a score table which has the user score for every user_id.

Now, my plan is to put the user table in one database, and score table in another database, making them two data sources. How can i handle such a scenario?